# Making sense of new vs old wiring schematic

Tags: diagram, schematic, hvac

I'm hooking up a new AC condenser fan and attached is the pic of the old and new diagrams.  Where should the new wires should go in reference to the old ones? They are run to a single 4 pin plug.

[image: fan schematic]

Comment: see this link on colour codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_wiring